# Is it possible to change the icon of a desktop application in javafx?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have a java desktop application made by JAVAFX. I have been able to make it executable and to install it inside my machine, but by default I have the icon of the coffee cup.

I would like to change the icon if it is possible to change it.

[image]

Comment: Spelling, title clarified

Comment: Yes, its possible, you might want to enable the "verbose build mode" to see where you have to place some ICO-file. How "to configure" is specific to your eclipse-project, but it IS possible without third-party tools.

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends upon the OS you are using it. There are some wrappers like JSmooth or launch4j. But generally...it's a manual work - change the icon like on any other app.

Good luck :)

Comment: You are telling me how to make an executable from jar, I have an exe using the inno setup compiler, I think I could change the icon using the Jlauncher and change it directly from there to an exe, am I correct?

Comment: JAR file does not have an icon, it's upon OS to give it one. Well as much as i know JSmooth creates EXE file and sets an icon to it. Not sure about JLauncher but I think it can do the trick too.

Comment: This is no real answer, just a comment. Please prefer real helping answers, not startung with "i think".